# How to have program shortcut icon open script along with program?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to have a script that works with a specific program open when I open that program with the program's shortcut icon. I have tried pasting the path into the target line in the icon's properties, but that didn't work. What do I need to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that I read  that you want to create an icon that looks like the original application launch icon, which will, when clicked, indeed launch the original application AND run some extra ahk code. You can create a `Shortcut` or `Link` to a ahk script that will launch your app (run, c:\path\yourapp.exe) and perform other tasks (WinWaitActive, your app) etc.. In the `link` to the ahk script (does not work on the real ahk script, ONLY with the `lnk` file) you can select the properties (right click) and change the icon to whatever you want (often you can use the icon of the original application, by pointing to the .exe (instead of selecting icons from the the standard shell32.dll). So by selecting the new icon to e.g. c:/program files/officexx/word.exe , your AHK script will get the icon as if it is the word launch icon. Hope that answers your question.

At the beginning of the script, but ater you execute the run command, you place the timer

```
Run, abc.exe
SetTitleMatchMode, 2
Sleep, 1000 ; Give the app some time to run before you start the test
SetTimer, CloseScript, 1000
Return

CloseScript:
IfWinExist, place the windows title here....
    Return
ExitApp
```

Comment: Robert,

Thanks very much as always. Getting the icon from the exe was a trick I didn't know. I put the command to run the exe at the beginning of the script, and it works beautifully.

Now, it would be nice to have a way to make the script exit when I close the program. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the first things that I did with AutoHotKey.  I wanted a 'wrapper' script for a program that I regularly used that lets me to chose different program options with a script GUI form when I press the F4 key while clicking the link.  Just clicking the link starts the program normally.  Eat your heart out Microsoft.

In the link's Start-In property I put the actual program's directory and my script gets the program name and other details from the script's command line arguments in the link's target property.